# How can I reset the WindowManager resolution and DPI settings in the Google TV user selection screen?

Tags: adb, android-tv, google-tv

I was experimenting with the `wm size` and `wm density` commands, and now the Google TV user selection screen does not let me pick a user, telling me that 1920x1080 is not a supported resolution when I do so.

Strangely, the resolution is not actually the problem, but rather the DPI, which is halved. Resetting the DPI with `wm density reset` allows me to select a user, but this must be done after every reboot.

How can I reset these broken settings?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused by a problematic resolution setting. When the resolution is set to 4K with a command like `wm size 3840x2160`, the WindowManager resolution stays at 1080p, but halves the emulated DPI. The 3840x2160 resolution setting gets saved, causing this behavior on every boot.

To permanently fix the issue, run the following commands on the user selection screen:

`wm size 1920x1080`
`wm density reset`